# Проблема с добавлением товара в корзину

Tags: jquery, virtuemart, joomla

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, как решить вопрос добавления товара в корзину по ссылке:

```
http://kaychyk-s.ru/index.php/my-cart.html?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=283&virtuemart_category_id=40
```

Вылезает следующая таблица. Как сделать, чтобы было нормально?

```
{
    "products": [{
        "product_page": "?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=283&virtuemart_category_id=40",
        "product_id": 283,
        "product_name": "Eko fanki lami",
        "description": "",
        "price": 3125.3,
        "quantity": 2,
        "product_full_image": "images\/stories\/virtuemart\/product\/3573.jpg",
        "product_thumb_image": "http:\/\/kaychyk-s.ru\/cache\/mod_ajax_dockcart\/6b717fbf310066948635f6efbdfffedd.png"
    }],
    "sum": "3687,85 \u0440\u0443\u0431",
    "succ": 1,
    "message": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересно, откуда ж эта "таблица вылезает"? А вообще, это строка в  формате json. И для преобразования её в объект или массив, существует функция [json_decode](http://php.ru/manual/function.json-decode.html)

Смотрите [пример тут](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yqx-4et)

Comment: Просто ее преобразовать и заменить я правильно понял?

Comment: @spectr, преобразовываете в массив, а что с этим массивом дальше делать - это уже вам должно быть известно. Я как телепат не состоялся ))

P.S. И все-таки, а откуда ж он "вылазит"? ))

Comment: при добавлении товара в корзину )

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться..

Comment: @Deonis, зайти по ссылке и жмакнуть по кнопочке "добавить в корзину". Там будет POST формы на index.php, который вместо осмысленного HTML и выдаёт этот массив. Так что ответ на вопрос "что нужно сделать" не такой уж и очевидный :-)

Comment: @klopp, я не сталкивался с VirtueMart и не намерен с ним иметь дело в дальнейшем, поэтому не в курсе, что там за чем идет и куда и что выводит. В своих проектах, где используется "корзина", я преобразовываю данные в json для того, чтоб сохранить их в куки или localStorage, но дело в том, что они у меня нигде не вылазят, как сказал ТС )) Вот мне и сатало любопытно.

Comment: Так я к тому, что здесь не на хэшкоде спрашивать надо, а брать программиста и внедрять его в систему :) Я тоже ничего не знаю про VM, просто предполагаю это по характеру "неисправности", увидев как она воспроизводится.

Comment: Значит заменой кода дело не закончится? Как же сделать что бы товар добавлялся в корзину?

Comment: @spectr, вам надо подождать того, кто имел дело с VM. А пока я могу сказать следующее - при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить в корзину", идет переход по такому URL *http://kaychyk-s.ru/index.php/index.php*, что на мой взгляд абсолютно не логично. Попробуйте в форме изменить значение атрибута **action** на **"/index.php"**.